# re-assign instance variable, is it better to set nil first

Tags: objective-c, instance-variables

I am using XCode 7.3.1.

I have a instance variable:

```
mProduct = [[Product alloc] initWithName:@"apple"];
```

later on in the same class, I need to re-assign a new object to this instance variable, I know I can just do:

```
mProduct = [[Product alloc] initWithName:@"Car"];
```

But I am wondering, **is it better** to first set `mProduct` to `nil` before re-assign a new instance to the variable?

```
mProduct = nil;
mProduct = [[Product alloc] initWithName:@"Car"];
```

Comment: Both are initialization. Unless you need "apple" as a value of `mProduct` there is no need to initialize `mProduct` with "apple" or `nil` for that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will make no difference at all.

Either way ARC will correctly handle memory, deallocating memory as needed if the old object is no longer in use in your program.